# Where can I find an English dictionary that I can search by number of syllables, transitive/intransitive, and other grammatical markers?

Tags: discussion, resources, online-resources

I need to find lists of English words that meet certain criteria, such as having a certain number of syllables, or being intransitive verbs. Is there an online English dictionary that will allow me to search for this kind of grammatical "tag" rather than by specific words?

Comment: A certain number of syllables is a phonetic or phonological criterion rather than a grammatical one. You could use Ben Briedis's "[Phonetic Word Search](http://www.benbriedis.com/phonetic/search.php)" to help you with finding words that meet that criterion. I can't think of a resource that lets you search for intransitive verbs specifically.

Comment: It has quite a lot to do with grammar, however. It's a valid question; dictionaries have a lot of information but it's often hard to extract it.

Comment: Fun resource: https://www.howmanysyllables.com

Comment: Rhyming dictionaries often list words by number of syllables